# What is the correct way of cloning and installing a project that involves typescript `@types`?

Tags: typescript, types

I was working on a project that involved installing some `@types`.

```
npm install react react-dom typescript @types/react @types/react-dom --save
```

It worked wonderfully. However, when I try and `git clone` and then `npm install` the project on another machine... It doesn't install any of the `@types` and actually just removes them from the `package-lock.json`. What is the correct way of cloning and installing this project?

Comment: It doesn't behave like that at all.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Do you mind elaborating on that please?

Comment: I mean that install command does not behave the way you describe it. It absolutely adds all of the packages, including scoped packages such as `@types/whatever`, to both the package and lock files such that they are installed by those who clone the repository and then run the install command. In other words, you have some other problem.

Comment: Well... I am following this article (https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/typescript-react-getting-started#module-gettingstartedfromscratch). It works. However, as I said, when I git clone the project on another machine and simply type `npm install`... The `package-lock.json` instantly shows that the `@types` have been removed from the installation.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am doing nothing except 1. git clone 2. npm install... Then the types go missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I found that `package.json` was actually missing the `@types` altogether! It was only `package-lock.json` that seemed to reference them alone!! As a result, when I was running `npm install`, they were just being removed from `package-lock.json`, since they were not present in `package.json`.

However, this has caused me to re-evaluate whether `package-lock.json` should be included as part of the git repository, to begin with. Had it not been for `package-lock.json`, I would not have been under the false impression that `@types` were already a part of `package.json`. Besides, different machines have different software make-ups and very possibly different dependency version requirements. To "lock" these dependencies at particular versions unnecessarily and then try to force these upon the different operating system setups... Just doesn't make sense anymore.

When `package.json` is cloned, `npm install` should be able to figure out the correct `package-lock.json` versioning, and regenerate it anyway! Under normal circumstances, I no longer see why `package-lock.json` should be a part of git and forced upon anyone!

Comment: I'm glad you got this worked out, but your conclusion absolutely contradicts NPM's documentation. You must check in your lock file or else your install will not be stable. This can lead to subtle and highly obscure bugs.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you know where in the NPM documentation this is documented? I would really like to understand these "subtle and highly obscure bugs"! Thanks.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Besides, after some research... I am not sure this matter is as black and white as you presume. There seems to be a difference of opinion amongst some users.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Here is just one example of many, which describe why `package-lock.json` SHOULD be git ignored.

https://dev.to/gajus/stop-using-package-lock-json-or-yarn-lock-3ddi

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mixture of opinions on the topic. However, I happen to know for a fact that your issue was due your package not listing the types packages as dependencies is in the `package.json` file. Having the lock file in git is still a separate concern because these packages are just like any others. I just don't want you to give the impression that the lock file caused the actual issue

Comment: @AluanHaddad Perhaps, I was clear not enough. The issue WAS to do with package-lock.json, albeit indirectly. Anyway, I have elaborated on my answer above... And I no longer think that it deserves the downvote that was assigned to it. We need to remind ourselves that differences in opinion should be embraced, and "my way or the highway" mentality should be avoided.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ooh, looks like more people having problems with `package-lock.json`. This link provides a way to disable auto-generation of this problematic file. https://www.codementor.io/@johnkennedy/get-rid-of-that-npm-package-lock-json-e0bj7ai42